# Contacts Server (selfhosting)

Tags: self-hosted, contact-manager

I would like to store my contacts/addressbook on my own server.

Required features:

- self-hosted
- open source
- can sync to Android and Thunderbird
- Runs on linux

Comment: Just for contacts (and nothing else), Nextcloud would be a bit overkill, as there are more leight-weight solutions like Baïkal or Radicale (AFAIR both for contacts and calendars).

Comment: @Izzy if you have experience with one of these tools, please write an answer. I have used tine20 and nextcloud, and I like nextcloud very much. Works well.

Comment: I also use Nextcloud, as I need more than just contacts & calendar. The other 2 I have not used myself, otherwise I had written an answer :) I only know 2nd hand that the two should work well and are resource friendly. // Never heard of tine20, though.

Comment: Not used it myself, but https://sabre.io/baikal/ mentioned above has been recommended in past by other people.

Answer (score 0):

Nextcloud can do this. See https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/contacts

It is ready for self-hosting, open source, can sync to Android and Thunderbird and runs on linux.

Docs how to sync with thunderbird are here: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/13/user_manual/pim/sync_thunderbird.html

You need the thunderbird plugin CardBook.